# Custom changelog in Jenkins Pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was wondering if it is possible to have a custom changelog appear for Jenkins Pipelines. Ideally, I'd like to propagate the downstream changelogs, but failing that I've tried to create a custom changelog derived from the downstream builds. However, it doesn't appear to work (with no option for viewing the pipeline's workspace either).

I was wondering if this is something that I'm just getting wrong or whether it's actually supported or not.

This is the sample code I'm testing with

```
node('master')
{
    stage('Source')
    {
        build 'SourceBuild' 

        def rootDir = currentBuild.rawBuild.getRootDir().toString()
        echo rootDir
        def changelog = new File(rootDir, "changelog.xml")
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(changelog));
        writer.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        writer.println("<changelog>");
        writer.println(String.format("\t\t<user>%s</user>", 'User'));
        writer.println(String.format("\t\t<comment>Change</comment>", 'Comment'));
        writer.println("\t</changeset>");
        writer.println("</changelog>");
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins pipeline, I noticed that there is a global variable named `currentBuild`. It has a readable property called changeSets. I would rather take this approach with pipeline instead of playing around with changelog.xml

```
stage('some name') {
    def gitChangeSetList = currentBuild.changeSets
    formatGitChangeLog(gitChangeSetList)
}

def formatGitChangeLog(GitChangeSetList changeSetList) {
    def formatStr = ""
        for (setItem in changeSetList) {
            for (change in setItem.getLogs()) {
                formatStr += "${change.getAuthor().getDisplayName()}: ${change.getMsg()}\n"
            }
        }
    return formatStr
}
```

`currentBuild.changeSets` is of type [GitChangeSetList](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/git/hudson/plugins/git/GitChangeSetList.html). From the javadoc, we can derive various methods involved in [GitChangeSet](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/git/hudson/plugins/git/GitChangeSet.html).